# Problems setting up Python

Tags: python, command, package, installation

I recently installed python 3.3.2 
Im trying to install NumPy, when I call import NumPy from the command line I get the following error:

```
import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

From what I've read it may have to do with having multiple version of Python installed.
The only problem is when I try run the Which Python command I get another error?

```
which python
  File "<console>", line 1
    which python
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You need to run `which python` in Bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do depends on the operating system you are using. I'me assuming you are using Linux. If you are using Linux with some kind of package manager, you should use a numpy package that is expressly for the python version you want to us it with. The same goes if you are using windows.

Note that you can have different versions of python installed, but in general only *one* is symlinked to `python`. Running `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` should tell you what is the default version on your machine. If you have multiple versions, there should also be programs named `python2` and `python3`. Using `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python2` and `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3` will show you the which versions you really have.

On linux and other UNIX-like systems, you can usually find Python's files in a subdirectory of `/usr/local/lib`. For python 2.7 this will be `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`, for 3.2 it will be `/usr/local/lib/python3.3`. These directories will have a subdirectory `site-packages`. In those `site-packages` you should look for a subdirectory `numpy`. If you find `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy` but not `/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/numpy`, then numpy was not installed for 3.2.

**Edit**: In Windows, Python usually installs itself in the root of the C: drive, like `C:\Python27` or `C:\Python33`. I don't have a windows machine handy, but there should be a `site-packages` subdirectory in both of them as well. Look for the `numpy` subdirectory in there.

For windows, you can find precompiled binaries for mumpy [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). You just need to know is you have a 32 bit (`win32`) or 64 bit version (`amd64`) of windows. E.g. for python 3.3 and 2 32-bit windows I would suggest `numpy-MKL-1.7.1.win32-py3.3.‌exe`.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 unfortunately, Thanks for the advice though

Comment: Thanks Roland, Its working perfectly now, annoying that the import statement isn't working though

Answer (score 1):

Type open a command prompt and type `python` It will then tell you what version you are running as it opens the interactive python editor.

Otherwise get your numpy from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)  These are compiled binaries and should be the most straightforward to install for a windows user

Comment: It only returned 3.3.2, does mean theres only one version installed?

Comment: @Steve2056726 Not necessarily.  You can check for multiple python versions by going to C:\ and looking for the Python33 folder.  If there are multiple folders, like Python27, then you have multiple versions.

Comment: no, it does mean that only the python shell that has just started has version 3.3.2.

Comment: @Steve2056726: It means that python 3.3.2 installed itself as the main python.

Comment: Ok I think I only have the one, I've been reading some more and it might have to do with setting my environment variables, I set it to : C:\Python33\libs  - Is that correct?

Comment: @Steve2056726: other than letting the installer associate `.py` files with the Python interpreter, you shouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: @Steve2056726 no, your path should include **just** C:\Python33